# Using GroupBy to compute average or count based on the whole data until the corresponding date

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, linq-to-entities

I have the `AssessmentItems` DB object which contains the items about: Which user evaluated (`EvaluatorId`), which submission (`SubmissionId`), based on which rubric item (or criteria)(`RubricItemId`) and when (`DateCreated`).

I group by this object by `RubricItemId` and `DateCreated` to get compute some daily statistics based on each assessment criteria (or rubric item).

For example, I compute the `AverageScore`, which works fine and returns an output like: `RubricItem: 1, Day: 15/01/2019, AverageScore: 3.2`.

```
_context.AssessmentItems
        .Include(ai => ai.RubricItem)
        .Include(ai => ai.Assessment)
        .Where(ai => ai.RubricItem.RubricId == rubricId && ai.Assessment.Submission.ReviewRoundId == reviewRoundId)
        .Select(ai => new
        {
            ai.Id,
            DateCreated = ai.DateCreated.ToShortDateString(),//.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-dd"),
            ai.CurrentScore,
            ai.RubricItemId,
            ai.Assessment.SubmissionId,
            ai.Assessment.EvaluatorId

        })
        .GroupBy(ai => new { ai.RubricItemId, ai.DateCreated })
        .Select(g => new
        {
            g.Key.RubricItemId,
            g.Key.DateCreated,
            AverageScore = g.Average(ai => ai.CurrentScore),
            NumberOfStudentsEvaluating = g.Select(ai => ai.EvaluatorId).Distinct().Count(),

        }).ToList();
```

What I want to do is to compute the average until that day. I mean instead of calculating the average for the day, I want to get the average until that day (that is, I want to consider the assessment scores of the preceding days). The same why, when I compute `NumberOfStudentsEvaluating`, I want to indicate the total number of students participated in the evaluation until that day.

One approach to achieve this could be to iterate through the `result` object and compute these properties again:

```
 foreach (var i in result)
 {
     i.AverageScore = result.Where(r => r.DateCreated <= i.DateCreated).Select(r => r.AverageScore).Average(),

 }
```

But, this is quite costly. I wonder if it is possible to tweak the code a bit to achieve this, or should I start from scratch with another approach.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve], including sample input data.

Comment: Use result.Key.DateCreated since you grouped items by the date.  Not sure why it is costly since you already did a Group.  Recomend use ai.DateCreated.Date so you truncate the hours and minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split the query into two halves, you can compute the average as you would like (I also computed the `NumberOfStudentsEvaluating` on the same criteria) but I am not sure if EF/EF Core will be able to translate to SQL:

```
var base1 = _context.AssessmentItems
    .Include(ai => ai.RubricItem)
    .Include(ai => ai.Assessment)
    .Where(ai => ai.RubricItem.RubricId == rubricId && ai.Assessment.Submission.ReviewRoundId == reviewRoundId)
    .Select(ai => new {
        ai.Id,
        ai.DateCreated,
        ai.CurrentScore,
        ai.RubricItemId,
        ai.Assessment.SubmissionId,
        ai.Assessment.EvaluatorId

    })
    .GroupBy(ai => ai.RubricItemId);

var ans1 = base1
            .SelectMany(rig => rig.Select(ai => ai.DateCreated).Distinct().Select(DateCreated => new { RubricItemId = rig.Key, DateCreated, Items = rig.Where(b => b.DateCreated <= DateCreated) }))
            .Select(g => new {
                g.RubricItemId,
                DateCreated = g.DateCreated.ToShortDateString(), //.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-dd"),
                AverageScore = g.Items.Average(ai => ai.CurrentScore),
                NumberOfStudentsEvaluating = g.Items.Select(ai => ai.EvaluatorId).Distinct().Count(),
            }).ToList();
```